# C# WPF: Changing current tab with button click?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I would like to have a button on tab1. When that button is clicked I would like to be taken to tab2. How do I make this happen?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: 'System.Windows.Controls.TabControl' does not contain a definition for 'SelectTab'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `SelectedIndex` property.

Example:

```
   <TabControl x:Name="myTabControl">
          <TabControl.Items>
                    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Tab1 Content" />
                            <Button Content="Go to Tab2" Margin="5" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Click="Button_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
                        <TextBlock Text="Tab2 Content" />
                    </TabItem>
          </TabControl.Items>
   </TabControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    myTabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
 }
```

Comment: @GeorgTrakl Or if you do not want to use indexes, you can name your tabs and set **myTabControl.SelectedItem = tabName**.